# jquery hide all image but not the first

Tags: jquery, image, makefile, slide, effect

Hello all im trying to make this slide effect http://tinyurl.com/628z32d

but im new to jquery so i need a little help :), how can i hide all the big image in the #big-mage div and hide them? and then only show the first.

do you guys have a good simple to understand slide effect tutorial i will be glad to :)

Thanks!

this is what i have http://jsfiddle.net/bF9xy/

Comment: Please remove the make tag - your question has nothing to do with the make program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$("div img").hide().filter(":first-child").show();
```

or use the [$.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to filter out unwanted elements:

```
$("img").not("img.class-not-to-select").hide();
```

Comment: i think i should use the :first

Comment: $("div img").hide().filter(":first-child").show(); this works but it hide all the big image and only show the first small image :d i have try target it with $('#big-image img') but dident work

Comment: ups i have hide the div in my CSS :D

Comment: This works $("#big-image img").hide().filter(":first-child").show(); Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
$("img:gt(0)").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("div#big-mage img:not(:first)").hide();
```